# How to fill combobox from jTable

Tags: jcombobox

I am working on a project that does not need database connection. I have a trouble in filling value in a combo-box from jtable column. Please i need help.

```
public void Fillcombo1() {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable4.getModel();
    cmbSearch2.addItem((String)model.getValueAt(jTable4.getSelectedColumn(), 0));    
}
```

Comment: You say you're having trouble but it's hard for us to know what isn't working. Are you getting an error? Is the combobox not populated at all?

Comment: it didn't show error, but it couldn't be populated.